# $\|A\|,\|B\|\leq 1$. How do I prove $\left(\begin{array}{}1&A&AB\\A^*&1&B\\B^*A^*&B^*&1\end{array}\right)$ is positive.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

$A,B$ are elements of a unital C*-algebra $\mathscr A$ with $\|A\|\leq 1$ and $\|B\|\leq 1$.

$X=\left(\begin{array}{}1&A&AB\\A^*&1&B\\B^*A^*&B^*&1\end{array}\right)\in M_3(\mathscr A)=\mathscr A\otimes M_3(\mathbb C)$ .

I tried to find a matrix such that $Y^*Y=X$ and failed.

Then I tried to show the invertibility of $X+\lambda$ for $\lambda>0$. This is equivalent to the invertibility of $X$ for $\|A\|,\|B\|<1$. And failed again.

Could you please give me some hint?

Comment: Shouldn't the top right entry be $AB$ or the bottom left entry be $B^*$?

Comment: @Rammus You are right! It's $AB$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint
$$
\pmatrix{ 1&0&0\\-A^*&1&0\\0&-B^*&1}
\pmatrix{1&A&AB\\A^*&1&B\\B^*A^*&B^*&1}
\pmatrix{ 1&-A&0\\ 0&1&-B\\0&0&1}
= 
\pmatrix{1&0&0 \\ 0& 1-A^*A &0 \\ 0&0&1-B^*B}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another elegant solution:

$\left(\begin{array}{}A&0&0\\1&0&0\\B^*&0&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{}A^*&1&B\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{}AA^*&A&AB\\A^*&1&B\\B^*A^*&B^*&B^*B\end{array}\right)\leq \left(\begin{array}{}1&A&AB\\A^*&1&B\\B^*A^*&B^*&1\end{array}\right)$